# In my IOS app, how do I open create an sqlite3 database that I can use throughout my program?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am trying to do this:

```
sqlite3 *db;
self.dbPath = "tasks.sqlite";
int result = sqlite3_open(self.dbPath, &db);
```

The code after this is is throwing errors.  So I suspect that it is not working.  What should I pass in as the path?

Comment: Is that how you're making the db path?  My understanding is that you need to write to the Documents directory, which is given by the first entry in the array returned by `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);`

Comment: Also, are you including the sqlite libraries?  What *are* the error messages that you are seeing?  They will be a lot more helpful than "it's not working".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *strDatabaseName;
NSString *strDatabasePath;

-(void)getDatabase 
{
strDatabaseName = @"questionsdb.sqlite";    
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
strDatabasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:strDatabaseName];
}

-(BOOL) checkAndCreateDatabase {
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:strDatabasePath];
if(success) {
    return TRUE;
}
else {
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:strDatabaseName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:strDatabasePath error:nil];
}
return FALSE;
}
```

then from any method

```
sqlite3 *database;
if(sqlite3_open([strDatabasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
{
//doSomething
}
```

I hope it works for you as well.
thank you.